# Java 9 with Maven - modules not found

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-3, java-9

I'm working on the migration of our project from Java 8 to Java 9.

Using: IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5

Maven version: 3.5.1

So far, I created `module-info.java` for all the modules I'd like to migrate. Here, `requires` works well with `java.base`. But all other external modules/dependencies do not, let's say for example log4j and packages from our project that are not yet migrated to Java 9. These packages are also added as dependencies in the POM. However, IntelliJ doesn't throw an error here.
 [Navigation from `module-info.java` to the corresponding JAR in `External Libraries` works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcRd9.png)

But as soon as I run the build with `clean install`, there is a compilation failure: `module not found: log4j`. Same with all other external packages.

Any idea why this error occurs? I thought non-modular dependencies will be turned into an automatic module by Java 9. What am I doing wrong or didn't understand the right way?

Here is the project's POM:

```
<groupId>de.project</groupId>
<artifactId>basicProject</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>Basic Project</name>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                    <compilerVersion>3.7.0</compilerVersion>
                </configuration>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <!-- here the phase you need -->
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>../output/intern/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>intern</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>loggingConfig.xml</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <!--<filtering>true</filtering>-->
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.build.resourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.resourceEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>some_repository</id>
        <name>somerepos</name>
        <url>http://some.rep.de/plugin/repo/everything</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <!--the first project -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>firstProject</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--the second project -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>secondProject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>thirdProject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>fourthProject</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.someitextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>someitextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.lzf0349</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdatepicker</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--libs for testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Project structure:

- Project SDK: 9.0 (java version "9.0.1")
- Project language level: 9 - Modules, private methods in interfaces etc.
- Module SDK: Project SDK (9.0)
- Modules --> Sources --> Language level: 9 - Modules, private methods in interfaces etc.
- Platform Settings: SDK: 9.0, JDK home path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1

Comment: Could you update the question with your `pom.xml` configuration and project structure in use? By the way, do make sure you're using Java9 compatible versions of maven(plugins etc.).

Comment: Thanks, nullpointer. Updated the question, hope this helps.

Comment: Your maven-compiler-plugin version and configuration details seem weird. `<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                </configuration>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
            </plugin>`

Comment: Do u have a "require log4j;" in your module-info.java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. What I finally did and worked was to insert the build-element from a pom created by Eclipse in my pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>9</source>
                        <target>9</target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>9</source>
                        <target>9</target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <source>9</source>
                <target>9</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: This gave me a cryptic InvalidArgumentException. Changing the version to 3.8.0 solved it. No idea why. #letschangeversionnumbersrandomly #seniorjavadev

Answer (score 13):

I make this another answer because not everyone may read the comments...

For me the `maven-compiler-plugin` version was the problem. It seems modules are only supported since `3.8.0`.

So here are the parts from my `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <maven.compiler.source>9</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>9</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Once again I fell for this... JetBrains should make this the default version that is used in their auto generated maven projects.

Comment: Just a note: I also fell into the trap of multiple packages not found. That was bc. I was using the following maven-compiler-plugin:  `maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1-jboss-1` it seems that the jboss compiler plugin does not support modules in that version. switching to 3.8.1 and the normal plugin worked for me, so thanks! this led me on the right track :)